# Transform SQL data set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have sql table data set as follows

```
 SheetNo  VersioId ColumnId Value
  Sheet1    1      column1     3
  Sheet1    3      column1     7
  Sheet1    1      column2     A
  Sheet1    1      column3     Z
  Sheet1    4      column3     T
  Sheet1    1      column5     R
  Sheet1    2      column5     Q
```

I want to write a SQL query to transform this data set as follows

```
 SheetNo  VersioId ColumnId Value
 Sheet1    3      column1     7
 Sheet1    1      column2     A
 Sheet1    4      column3     T
 Sheet1    2      column5     Q
```

What I really need is get each column value of its maximum version Id. can some one help me on this

Comment: you want to keep the original data, or delete all but the "max" version of each "dupe"? `select sheetno, versioid, columnid, max(value) ... group by sheetno, versioid, columnid`?

Comment: I don't want to delete.I just need a select query

Comment: Can you explain why you would return `Sheet1    1      column2     A` for VersionId = 1? Why not `Sheet1    1      column5     R` or does it not matter?

Comment: I still do not understand what you want to achieve?
Do you want the max version for each value and each column or the max value for each version and each column?

Comment: In my data set I have version id 3 and 1 for column1. I want to select version3 value. Like that for all the columns get the latest version id's value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help you :

```
select y1.* from YourTable y1
join
(select Columnid,max(versionid) versionid from YourTable 
group by Columnid) as y2
on y1.Columnid = y2.Columnid and y1.versionid = y2.versionid
```

Comment: I should have been more rigorous. Yours certainly will out perform mine according to the query plans.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, get your SheetNo and ColumnId from the base table, then cross apply to grab the top by VersioId for VersioId and Value. Group results to collapse rows, and order to your liking. The same structure can be used to grab other data by max of some different column. See the [SqLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d78de/1).

```
select A.SheetNo, B.VersioId, A.ColumnId, B.Value
from Sheets A
  cross apply (
    select top 1 VersioId, Value
    from Sheets C
    where C.SheetNo = A.SheetNo
      and C.ColumnId = A.ColumnId
    order by C.VersioId desc
    ) B
group by A.SheetNo, B.VersioId, A.ColumnId, B.Value
order by A.SheetNo, A.ColumnId
```